# How to create one row/column matrix in PARI/GP

Tags: matrices

I need one column only matrix in PARI/GP, as I have an inner procedure which gets matrix as a parameter and iterates through all their columns. At the initial stage matrix is one column only (so one iteration is to be performed).

It is easy to create a matrix when it has at least 2 rows, and at least 2 columns:

```
m=[1,2,3,;4,5,6]
```

But how can one create a matrix with only one row or one column? I tried following:

```
m=[4,5,6] - creates a vector
m=[[4,5,6]] - creates a vector of vectors
m=[4,5,6;] - generates an error
```

Comment: Matrix with one column : [1;2;3;4;5]

Comment: I tired `m1c=[1;2;3;4;5]` and after `m1c[2,1]` and it works! :) Thanks @MathBot. But actually how to create a one row matrix, so I can refer to it's element like: `m1r[1,2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create one column matrix separate components by semicolons .

For example `m1c=[a;b;c;d;e]` gives the matrix with one column and five rows .

To create one row matrix separate components by semicolons and add sign tilde (`~`) at the end.

For example `m1r=[a;b;c;d;e]~` gives the matrix with one row and five columns .